# Setting alternative minimum and maximum parameters

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, max, min

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Temperature Growth rate Standard Error  Weight  Result
0   14.0        0.363       0.110           9.091   0.000
1   18.0        0.677       0.043           23.256  0.767
2   22.0        0.822       0.044           22.727  0.975
3   26.0        0.936       0.073           13.699  0.975
4   30.0        0.897       0.051           19.608  0.767
5   34.0        0.000       0.000           0.000   0.000
```

I'm trying to use it to set up either a function or an if loop that basically says if the algae doesn't grow at the minimum temperature of 14 or the maximum of 34, then the next minimum parameter available for positive growth (i.e. above 0) should be less then or equal to 18 and greater than 14, and the next maximum greater than or equal to 30 and less than 34. My thinking is whether I should generate a new column in the df that takes this into account, or whether I should do this irrespective of the given values. The final output I expect to produce is a curve fit that takes the optimised parameter values (essentially a scatter-style plot), and measures the temperatures against the updated or modelled growth rates (marked 'Results').

Here's how I set up the initial parameters:

```
def boatman_temperature_function(temp, max_growth_rate, min_temp, temp_range, skewness, kurtosis):
    num = temp - min_temp
    denom = temp_range - min_temp  # temp_range is the maximum temperature
    inside_sin = np.pi*((num/denom)**skewness)
    sin_result = np.sin(inside_sin) # TODO: numpy.sin input: radian? degree?
    final = max_growth_rate*(sin_result**kurtosis)
    return(final)
```

This is designed to be more of a hypothesis than a basis of the values I have in the df, but I think there's a way I can use this function with the 'Growth rate' and 'Result' columns.

In the meantime, I'm trying to explore the following 2 potential solutions, but I'm not quite sure how to make them work. Any suggestions?

Here's the first solution:

```
for value in df2:
    if df2['Temperature'].min() == 14 & df2['Growth rate'] == 0:
        df2['Temperature'].min() <= 18
        if df2['Temperature'].max() == 34 & df2['Growth rate'] == 0:
            df2['Temperature'].max() >= 30
```

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

And here's the second:

```
def min_and_max_alts(temp, growth_rate, alternate):
    df2[alternate] = np.where((df2[temp].min() == 14 & df2[growth_rate] == 0), df2[temp].max() == 34 & df2[growth_rate] == 0)
    return df2

df2 = min_and_max_alts('Temperature','Growth rate','Alternate growth rate')
df2
```

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool] (basically same result as the first attempted solution)
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this?

Comment: Yes what are you trying to do, insert new rows with adjusted temperatures? Just check whether rows that follow a row matching your no-growth and temperature conditions follow your temperature adjustment?

Comment: If the organism did not grow at the lower temperature (14°C), then a zero is reported. In this instance, when defining Tmin in the model fit, constrain the parameter to be equal to or greater than 14°C and less than 18°C (which is the next temperature treatment which has a positive growth rate). 

If the organism did not grow at the highest temperature (34°C), then a zero is reported. In this instance, when defining Tmax in the model, constrain the parameter to be equal to or less than 34°C and greater than 30°C (which is the next temperature treatment which has a positive growth rate).

Comment: @SamColeman Where/how do you defined these Tmin and Tmax? That’s the output you  seem to want but you don’t mention them in your question

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you are trying to do. I think you should rewrite your question with an example of the expected output.

Comment: @HakanAkgün I've tried rephrasing the question, including my desired output. Hopefully should clear things up a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what you want(since it's a bit ambiguous) but I'm posting the answer we can discuss later.

Answer (score 0):

This function changes the min, max with desired min, max values:

```
def change_temp(row,value_for_min,value_for_max):
    T,R=row[0],row[1]
    if R==0:
        if T==14:
            T=value_for_min
            print(f"Min value changed as {value_for_min}")
        elif T==34:
            T=value_for_max
            print(f"Max value changed as {value_for_max}")
    return T
DF["Temperature"]=DF[["Temperature","Growth"]].apply(lambda row: change_temp(row,18,30),axis=1)
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I see what you're getting at here, but I'd like to use this function in a way that also factors in the 'Growth Rate (not the 'Result', I clarified with the Researcher). So when I try it, I get two copies of 18 and 30 (so 18 where 14 was and 30 where 34 was). I'd probably look to use this statement more as a double-check hypothesis as the basis for a plot, rather than a dataframe modification, although considering there is already growth at the lower end of the temperature spectrum (14), but not at the higher end (34), I'd like to factor that into my working where possible.

Comment: Sorry, mistakenly I've given the result rather than Growth. In the beginning, I've created for the growth rate. Can you clarify what's wrong with this and what you want?

Comment: So when I try your suggested code and call the df I get a completely different output from the df below:

```
 Temperature Growth rate Standard Error Weight Result Alternate growth rate
0 14.0 0.363 0.110 9.091 0.000 
1 18.0 0.677 0.043 23.256 0.767 
2 22.0 0.822 0.044 22.727 0.975 
3 26.0 0.936 0.073 13.699 0.975 
4 30.0 0.897 0.051 19.608 0.767 0.897
5 34.0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0
```

So the 14 and 34 both get replaced with 18 and 30, which means that I get duplicates. Ideally, I'd like to to set up a function with these constraints which I can apply in my final curve fit.

Comment: OK, so I think I've found a way to set up the function:

```
def alt_temp_limit(temp, growth_rate, low_temp, high_temp):
    for value in temp:
        if growth_rate in low_temp == 0:
            low_temp >= 14 & low_temp < 18
        else:
            low_temp = 14
            continue
    if growth_rate in high_temp == 0:
        high_temp <= 34 & high_temp > 30
    else:
        high_temp = 34
        return temp
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to apply this function accordingly to my final curve fit, but I don't know if creating a new df column is a practical step.

Comment: Here's what I've tried so far:

```
df2['Altered Parameters'] = df2[['Temperature', 'Growth rate']].apply(alt_temp_limit, axis = 1)

TypeError: alt_temp_limit() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'growth_rate', 'low_temp', and 'high_temp'
```